# IF Statement Returns FALSE Instead of the Specified Value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested-if

IF statement returns `FALSE` instead of the specified value

Below is the formula

`=IF(CJ6="Yes";IF(AND(CL6-CC6<=0);"0";IF(AND(CL6-CC6<=364;CL6-CC6>=0);(CL6-CC6);IF(CL6-CC6>364;"365";"0"))))`

May you advise on where the error is sitting in, I can't get to crack it.

Regards,
Morgs

Comment: It looks like the second parameter (what if false) for your first If() is missing -> What if CJ6 <> "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't specify [value_if_false] as Chris said above.

I fixed the formula. Now it gives the specified value:

```
=IF(CJ6="Yes";IF(AND(CL6-CC6<=0);"0";IF(AND(CL6-CC6<=364;CL6-CC6>=0);(CL6-CC6);IF(CL6-CC6>364;"365";"0")));"Desired Value")
```

The "Desired Value" is the if-false value of the first IF formula. You can change it to whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks Berkutay, I have copied the updated formula and it worked magic, However, I would like to extend the fomular as follows: IF(I="Yes") the True value shall be (Disposal Date - Capitalisation date; however the True Value should be limited to the following (a) (If DP-CP<=0 then the formular should  return"0" AND (b) (If DP-CP<364 and >0 then the formular should return the output value of (DP-CP) AND (c)(If DP-CP>=365 then the fomular should return "365") ______The False Value should return the same formulars with the substitution going to Disposal Date (It will be repalced by Year End (YE)

Comment: May you send me an email to: mukwevho7@yahoo.com

Comment: I will send you a template spreadsheet in order for you to assist